# Is it possible to set a customizable mode of "Do not disturb" for Outlook?

Tags: outlook, ms-office

In [this article](https://supertekboy.com/2018/07/21/do-not-disturb-in-outlook-mobile/), it is described how to set Outlook to e.g. do not disturb during weekends.

In addition to this, I would like to add the criteria to not disturb after work hours (i.e. 5 PM to 8 AM).

From my understanding, this is not possible? Could we persuade Microsoft to add this feature somehow?

**EDIT:** I found [that several others also want this feture](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/293346-outlook-for-android/suggestions/34575280-custom-schedule-for-do-not-disturb).

Answer (score 1):

The latest versions of the Outlook app actually already have this new DND option "**During evenings**" wherein you can configure your after-work routine. By default, it is set to 5PM to 8AM schedule as you want in your question. But it can also be modified to fit a different routine. Here's the screenshot:

[image: Outlook Android]

Comment: I just updated the app to version 4.0.94. But I don't have that function. Maybe the version patched to Google Play varies depending on the region. I live in Finland. Perhaps Google's server for apps in Europe is not as up to date as other places in the world.

Comment: @tomatoeshift I'm on the version 4.0.94, last updates on 20th December. Which one are you at?

Comment: Now I got a second update on the same day. Now I have the DOD settings as in your screenshot